# Creating a program that will generate x random values that all add to 100

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, I am trying to create a program that generates random numbers:

```
from random import *
x = 10
for i in range(x):
    print(randint(0, 100))
```

This program generates 10 random numbers between 0 and 100, like so:

```
81
92
86
26
78
85
28
32
79
20
```

But as you can see, this does not match my title. I want all these values to add up to 100. Is there anyway I can do this? Here is an example of what I would like:

```
11
13
42
4
5
2
3
10
5
5
```

(These are all randomised numbers, in this instance)

To summarise:
Is there anyway to generate a set of random numbers that all sum up to one value?

Comment: Could you just generate 9 values and then do 100 (or whatever other value) - the sum of what's left? To make sure you don't preemptively go over, you could progressively reduce the maximum number as you loop

Comment: What sort of distribution do you need in your "random numbers"?  Your lack of specificity makes this a trivial problem to solve.  Depending on the specification, it could get tricky.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

reqd_sum = 100
x = 10
for _ in range(x-1):
    num = random.randint(0, reqd_sum)
    reqd_sum -= num
    print(num)
print(reqd_sum)
```

Comment: `65
14
19
2
0
0
0
0
0
0` This is the output I got. Does not seem very random.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
from random import random

x = 10

values = [random() for i in range(x)]
s = sum(values)
values = [int((i / s) * 100) for i in values]
values[-1] += 100 - sum(values) # add the remainder to 100

print('Values :', values)
print('Sum    :', sum(values))
```

Prints (for example):

```
Values : [4, 14, 5, 8, 14, 20, 6, 13, 12, 4]
Sum    : 100
```